# pythonで文字と数字が混ざる文章から、文字は１文字ずつ、数字はまとまりで頭から順番に処理する方法

Tags: python

タイトルの通り、
文字、数字が混ざる文章から文字は１文字ずつ、数字は次に文字が出るまでをひとまとまりとして処理したいです。
コードはpythonです。

例えば、

```
def printer(letter):
    # 本来は何らかの処理
    print(letter)

sentence = "きょうは19あしたは20"
for letter in sentence:
    if not letter.isdecimal():
        printer(letter)
    else:
        printer(letter)
```

だと、

```
き
ょ
う
は
1
9
あ
し
た
は
2
0
```

となりますが、

```
き
ょ
う
は
19
あ
し
た
は
20
```

と処理されるような方法を知りたいです。

Answer (score 5):

例えば正規表現を使うとこんな感じでできます。(python3です。)

```
import re

def printer(letter):
    # 本来は何らかの処理
    print(letter)

sentence = "きょうは19あしたは20"

for match in re.findall('[0-9]+|[^0-9]', sentence):
    printer(match)
```

結果:

> ```
> き
> ょ
> う
> は
> 19
> あ
> し
> た
> は
> 20
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`re.split()` を使ってみました。

```
import re

def printer(letter):
  # 本来は何らかの処理
  print(letter)

sentence = "きょうは19あしたは20"
##sentence = "きょうは１９あしたは２０"
[printer(c) for c in re.split('(\d+|\D)', sentence) if c not in [None, '']]
```

ちなみに、正規表現として `\d` を使っていますけれども、(ご存知かもしれませんが) python3 では `U+FF10` 〜 `U+FF19`(俗に言う「全角」文字)にもマッチします(`re.split()` の引数に `flags = re.ASCII` を追加すればマッチしなくなります)。